# Estilo de google maps, muestra cuadricula blanca

Tags: android, google-maps

Estoy implementando un estilo personalizado en un mapa de google maps, pero al momento de aplicarlo, la aplicación se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si quito el estilo al mapa, se ve perfectamente, el codigo que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(Mapa.this, R.raw.estilo_map);
        mMap.setMapStyle(style);
```

si dejo la variable **mMap.setMapStyle(style);** como boolean, me dice que se cargo correctamente

espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: Habilitaste a API Key con el SHA-1 del Keystore?

Comment: si, si quito el estilo, el mapa carga correctamente

Comment: Hola amigo @zhet acabo de notar que cargas un estilo , que contiene el archivo estilo_map ?

Comment: un estilo de mapa, lo probe en el wizard de estilos web de google maps y funciona correctamente